# Dcount in Microsoft Access expression

Tags: ms-access, expression

I've been trying to get dcount to work in an existing database with queries and report names that are the same and was giving myself a headache, so I created a simple 1 table db to test it out.

It has a field1 with these values
id1
id1
id2
id3

I want to count the number of distinct values.  i.e. get 3 from the above.
I created a report with a field in the report footer with the expression

```
=DCount("[Field1]","Table1")
```

..it returns 4

Yet when I check the microsoft site for the description of how dcount works, it distinctly says it counts distinct entries.
Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which page you are referring to, but `DCount` simply counts records, not distinct values.

To count distinct values, I suggest Allen Browne's "Extended DCount" aka `ECount` function: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-66.html

This page has also more information about how `DCount` works.

Comment: took some re-hunting, but here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DCount-function-counts-the-unique-values-in-a-record-set-227efeeb-5bb3-4343-8277-a0750daf3496
'The DCount function is what you need to count unique values in a specified set of records.'
However, that's neither here nor there.  
Thank you for the link.  Got that working perfectly in my little test db.  Was getting a FROM error in the real one, but changed the query name to be unique (from table, form and report names).  Now getting a 'Too few parameters', but will hunt it down.  Thank you again.